# Vb.net Get value of a variable name type into a text box

Tags: vb.net, variables

```
Public intUserID as integer = 1500
Function getvalue(variablename as string) as integer
return variablename
```

If a pass the variable name intUserID to the function how do I get the function to return 1500 and not intUserID.

In the end I used Gettype and FieldInfo. Sample code below. Works well if the variable is declare in module modDeclarations as public.

```
Dim VarType As Type = GetType(modDeclarations)
Dim fld As FieldInfo()

fld = VarType.getfield("intUserID")
if fld Is Nothing then
else
  variablename = fld.getvalue(intUserID)
end if
```

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? It's possible but it's generally not something you should have to do. If a beginner thinks they need to, it's usually because they're doing the wrong thing in the first place. Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than just how you're trying to achieve it, and we can probably suggest a better option. In the unlikely event that you really do need to identify a variable by name, at least we'll be sure.

Comment: We've created a subsystem to one of our systems that runs reports where all the parameters are store in a database. The the form with the parameters on it is create dynamically when the user select the report they would like to run. We need to pass some default paraments to stored procedures that are stored in variable in the system. These variable may vary from report to report. We don't want to change code for each report.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a `Dictionary` where the keys are type `String` and the values are whatever type is appropriate.

Comment: How would I get the key value to equal the variable.
Dim variables As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
variables.add("keyname",varibalename) how do you evaluate the variable name or am I total on the wrong path here.

Comment: There is no variable. That's the point. The values are what you would otherwise assign to the variables and the keys are what you would otherwise name the variables. You then get a key from the database and use it to index the dictionary to get the value. Done.